# Android Room flowable emits multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room, android-livedata

I'm using `Room` and `RxJava Flowable` to get changes from the database. the problem is when I  insert multiple items into the database, `flowable` emits multiple times in different sizes. I tried to use `distinctUntilChanged()` but it can't help since the size of the list is changing.

example:

**CarEntity:**

```kotlin
@Entity
data class CarEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val price: Int
)
```

**CarDao:**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface CarDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertSync(car: CarEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM CarEntity ORDER BY price DESC")
    fun cars(): Flowable<List<CarEntity>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM CarEntity")
    fun removeAll()
}
```

**insert items:**

```kotlin
fun insertCars() {
    val cars = arrayListOf<CarEntity>()
    for (i in 1..10) {
        cars.add(CarEntity(i, "car $i", i * 1000))
    }

    Single.just(cars)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map {
            dao.removeAll()
            it.forEach { car -> dao.insertSync(car)}
        }
        .subscribe(
            { println("debug: completed") },
            { println("debug: error ${it.message}") }
        )
        .apply { disposable.add(this) }
}
```

**observe flowable:**

```kotlin
dao.cars()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeBy { cars ->
        var result = ""
        cars.forEach { car -> result += "${car.id} " }
        println(result)
    }
    .apply { disposable.add(this) }
```

**Result:**

```
//first insert
3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

//second insert
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**How can I get the last value?**

**Is there any other way to achieve this?**

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Room `Insert` supports collections/array, you can make use of that instead of doing `forEach`

Comment: @Hussain thanks, post it as answer

Comment: Another way to approach this would be to `debounce` the cars flowable, so that it emits only "stable" values. This is a more generic approach, but with the downside of introducing latency.